# Find standard deviation of a column based of values from another column and group by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame looking like this:

```
classid  grade  haveTeacher
0        99     1
1        40     1
1        50     0
1        70     1
2        50     0
3        34     0
```

I'd like to find out what I could write in pandas to find out the standard deviation of "grade" across classid that have a teacher (1 means there is a teacher). I know we would have to groupby "classid", but I was wondering what would go inside the .apply and lambda function to fulfill all these conditionals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For improve performance first set missing values if no `1` in `haveTeacher` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then aggregate `std`:

```
df = (df['grade'].where(df['haveTeacher'].eq(1))
                 .groupby(df['classid'])
                 .std()
                 .reset_index(name='std'))
print (df)
   classid        std
0        0        NaN
1        1  21.213203
2        2        NaN
3        3        NaN
```

Solution suggested in question should be slow if large DataFrame:

```
df = (df.groupby('classid')
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['haveTeacher'].eq(1), 'grade'].std())
        .reset_index(name='std'))
print (df)
   classid        std
0        0        NaN
1        1  21.213203
2        2        NaN
3        3        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You might first want to get the dataframe with records having teacher - `df[df['haveteacher'] == 1]`. Once you get this you can do a `groupby(classid)` and use **numpy.std**  (`import numpy as np` before that ) function to find the standard devitation of that group
so you have -

```
>>> df[df['haveteacher'] == 1].groupby(['classid']).agg({'grade': np.std})
```

output is -

```
grade
classid           
0              NaN
1        21.213203
```